# full outer join problem - months without revenue

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

The problem I have is that I fail at implementing an outer join into the SQL code. I want the months without any revenue to be visible as either "0" or as "null" in the table. This is supposed to be done with an outer join.

```
with cte1 as (
select *
from (Values
    (1, 'jan'),
    (2, 'feb'),
    (3, 'mar'),
    (4, 'apr'),
    (5, 'may'),
    (6, 'jun'),
    (7, 'jul'),
    (8, 'aug'),
    (9, 'sep'),
    (10, 'oct'),
    (11, 'nov'),
    (12, 'dec')
) as T(monthnr, maand))
--This part calculates the monthly revenue (maand = month)
select x.regioncode, x.city, x.maand, x.monthlyrevenue, y.totalrevenue
from (
select v.regioncode, city, maand, COALESCE(SUM(oa.amount * pp.price), 0) as monthlyrevenue
from salesregion s
join employee e
on s.regionmgr = e.employeeID
join customer c
on left(c.postalcodehousenumber, 4) between s.pcbegin and s.pcend
join orders o
on o.customerID = c.customerID
join orderamount oa
on oa.orderid = o.orderid
join productprice pp
on pp.productid = oa.productid
join cte1
on month(orderdate) = monthnr
where (o.orderdate > pp.begindate and o.orderdate < pp.enddate) and year(orderdate) = 2014
group by regioncode, city, maand) x
CROSS JOIN
(--This code calculates the total revenue per city.
select city, SUM(oa.amount * pp.price) as totalrevenue
from salesregion s
join employee e
on s.regionmgr = e.employeeID
join customer c
on left(c.postalcodehousenumber, 4) between s.pcbegin and s.pcend
join orders o
on o.customerID = c.customerID
join orderamount oa
on oa.orderid = o.orderid
join productprice pp
on pp.productid = oa.productid
where (o.orderdate > pp.begindate and o.orderdate < pp.enddate) and year(orderdate) = 2014
group by city
)y
where x.city = y.city
```

I have figured out that the Outer Join has to be implemented in the top part of the part with the Cross Join, since the top part calculates the monthly revenue.
However, any attempt I make at trying to implement an Outer Join either fails or gives me bad values.

What I'm currently getting can be seen in the image below.
From left to right in the image is: **Regioncode, city, month, revenue, totalrevenue**.

What I'm trying to get as an output is to display all the months per city, even if they didn't have any revenue that month. Currently it only shows the months that have revenue that month (I want it to display City: Erp, Month: January, Revenue: either "0"  or "null". 
[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuNDC.png)

Comment: where are "br" and "ap" tables?

Comment: Hey Zeki, Forgot to change those, should've been the same as the sum calculation on the top part of the Cross Join query

Comment: The "b" table is missing as well.  Is it supposed to be o.orderdate?

Comment: Hey M. Wise, I guess I missed some while translating them, I've gone over them again and it should be fixed now. Thanks

Comment: From what table(s) do city and region come from?  IMO this would be easiest done by creating a second CTE that cross joins CTE1 to City, Region thus ensuring each city/region combo has all months.  then right join that to your base tables ensuring you move filters to the joins themselves. and eliminate the cross join to get revenue per city.  Then use window functions `sum(oa.amount) over (partition by month,city) as CityTotal`and `sum(oa.amount)  over (partition by month, region)  as RegionTotals`

Comment: Hey xQbert, City is part of Table "Customer" (the city that customer is from). Region is from table "salesregion"

Comment: Yeah I worked my way around that by doing a distinct on the CTE; would be faster and more accurate to go to the source tables though;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created 4 CTEs

- GetMonths - Your CTE1
- Revenue - Revenue by City, Region so the cross join later has to do less work.
- GetUniqueCityRegion - if you want all months by city/region then I needed this
- GetUniqueCityRegionMonth - This then gets all months for each city region.

. The issue for me was when you say see all months by what thus the need for a list of city regions by month

Completely untested as no tables/sample data has been provided and mocking this up would take too long.

```
WITH GetMonths as (SELECT *
              FROM (Values
                   (1, 'jan'),(2, 'feb'),(3, 'mar'),(4, 'apr'),(5, 'may'),(6, 'jun'),
                   (7, 'jul'),(8, 'aug'),(9, 'sep'),(10, 'oct'),(11, 'nov'),(12, 'dec')) as T(monthnr, maand)),
Revenue as (SELECT regioncode, city, sum(coalesce(oaamount*pp.price,0)) as RecordRevenue, month(o.Orderdate) as Mo 
            FROM salesregion s
            JOIN employee e
              on s.regionmgr = e.employeeID
            JOIN customer c
              on left(c.postalcodehousenumber, 4) between s.pcbegin and s.pcend
            JOIN orders o
              on o.customerID = c.customerID
            JOIN orderamount oa
              on oa.orderid = o.orderid
            JOIN productprice pp
              on pp.productid = oa.productid
            WHERE o.orderdate > pp.begindate 
              and o.orderdate < pp.enddate) 
              and year(o.orderdate) = 2014
            GROUP BY RegionCode, City),
GetUniqueRegionCity as (SELECT DISTINCT REGIONCODE, City 
         FROM Revenue)
GetUniqueRegionCityMonth as (SELECT RegionCode, City, monthnr, maand
         FROM GetUniqueRegionCity
         CROSS JOIN GetMonths)

--Now get the Total Revenue by City/Region  We left join to revenue from GetUniqueRegionCityMonth to ensure each city/region has all months
    SELECT x.regioncode
         , x.city
         , x.maand
         , x.monthlyrevenue
         , coalesce(sum(RecordRevenue) over (partition by x.city, R.Mo),0) as RevenueCity
         , coalesce(sum(RecordRevenue) over (partition by x.RegionCode, R.Mo),0) RevenueRegion
    FROM GetUniqueRegionCityMonth x
    LEFT JOIN Revenue R
      on R.RegionCode = x.RegionCode
     and R.City = x.City
     and R.Mo = x.MonthNr
```

Comment: Thank you @xQbert! With some additional changes I've been able to get the desired output.

Comment: Glad we could help. It always helps us to see sample data and expected results it eliminates quite a few questions.  In future questions be sure to include such details as it helps us; help you!

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but I moved a few things around to simplify your query.  The cross join to me looks like it produces the total revenue for each city over the entire time period rather than the monthly revenue, so I added in a sum function which removes the need of the "y" query altogether.  I may have misinterpreted your intent, so if it doesn't produce the correct result, try changing the field in the "partition" statement.  This will only work with SQL server 2012 and later:

```
with cte1 as (
select *
from (Values
(1, 'jan'),
(2, 'feb'),
(3, 'mar'),
(4, 'apr'),
(5, 'may'),
(6, 'jun'),
(7, 'jul'),
(8, 'aug'),
(9, 'sep'),
(10, 'oct'),
(11, 'nov'),
(12, 'dec')
) as T(monthnr, maand))
--This part calculates the monthly revenue (maand = month)
select x.regioncode
,x.city
,x.maand
,x.revenue
,sum(x.revenue) over (partition by x.maand) as MonthlyRevenue
from (
select s.regioncode, s.city, cte1.maand, COALESCE(SUM(cr.revenue), 0) as Revenue
from salesregion s
join employee e
on s.regionmgr = e.employeeID
join customer c
on left(c.postalcodehousenumber, 4) between s.pcbegin and s.pcend
cross join cte1
left join
(
select o.customerid
,m.monthnr
,sum(oa.amount * pp.price) as Revenue
from orders o
join orderamount oa
on oa.orderid = o.orderid
join productprice pp
on pp.productid = oa.productid
join cte1 m
on month(o.orderdate) = m.monthnr
where (o.orderdate > pp.begindate and o.orderdate < pp.enddate) and year(orderdate) = 2014
group by o.customerid, m.monthnr
) cr
on c.customerid = cr.customerid
and cte1.monthnr = cr.monthnr
group by s.regioncode, s.city, cte1.maand
) x
```

Comment: "PARTITION BY" can work with SQL Server 2008 and later.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add cross apply to find TotalRevenue. Simply you can use `SUM(City) OVER(PARTITION BY City)` 
I changed and tried to simplify your query. I believe it can help you.

```
WITH cte1
AS
(SELECT
        *
    FROM (VALUES(1, 'jan'),
    (2, 'feb'),
    (3, 'mar'),
    (4, 'apr'),
    (5, 'may'),
    (6, 'jun'),
    (7, 'jul'),
    (8, 'aug'),
    (9, 'sep'),
    (10, 'oct'),
    (11, 'nov'),
    (12, 'dec')
    ) AS T (monthnr, maand))
--This part calculates the monthly revenue (maand = month)
SELECT
    x.regioncode
   ,x.city
   ,cte1.maand
   ,x.monthlyrevenue
   ,x.totalrevenue
FROM cte1
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
            s.regioncode
           ,city
           ,MONTH(orderdate) OrderMonth
           ,COALESCE(SUM(oa.amount * pp.price), 0) AS monthlyrevenue
           ,SUM(COALESCE(SUM(oa.amount * pp.price), 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY city) totalrevenue
        FROM salesregion s
        JOIN employee e ON s.regionmgr = e.employeeID
        JOIN customer c ON LEFT(c.postalcodehousenumber, 4) BETWEEN s.pcbegin AND s.pcend
        JOIN orders o ON o.customerID = c.customerID
        JOIN orderamount oa ON oa.orderid = o.orderid
        JOIN productprice pp ON pp.productid = oa.productid
        WHERE (o.orderdate > pp.begindate
        AND o.orderdate < pp.enddate)
        AND YEAR(orderdate) = 2014
        GROUP BY s.regioncode
                ,city
                ,MONTH(orderdate)) x ON CTE1.monthnr = OrderMonth
```

Comment: Close; I think the cte1 needs first to be cross joined to a distinct region, city list (CTE2) or the left join will not include all cities or all regions and the join must be on 3 fields region, city and monthnr.

Comment: @xQbert I think he doesn't want to see all cities. He wants only all months even if there is no data. But if he want to see all regions and/or cities you are right, he need to create one/two more CTE for them.

Comment: I might have been unclear in what result I want to end up with. I have edited the original post and included an image to show what I'm currently getting as an output and tried to describe the desired output. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SjoerdW  The query which I provide should work for you. Did you get any problem with it?

Comment: @Zeki Gumus There seem to be an error in the select statement right after the Left Join. "sum(city) OVER (PARTITION BY city) totalrevenue". Did you mean something different with the first "city" as this gives me the "Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator"  error message

Comment: @SjoerdW it should be "COALESCE(SUM(oa.amount * pp.price), 0)" instead of City. I have corrected it.